# mySQL results in titlecase as JSON array | PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How to express the JSON array produced by a mySQL query in title case?

Meaning if the record in the database says John smith or JOHN SMITH it will show the record in the array as John Smith.

Currently this is what I have so far:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query(" `first`,`last`)
FROM `Table1` ");

$stmt->execute([]);

$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($row);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in PHP using [ucwords](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) function. Use it with [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

```
$a = 'John SNOW';
$strCamelCase = ucwords(strtolower($a));

Output:
John Snow
```

So you can do the following

```
$sql = "SELECT `first`,`last` FROM `Table1`";
$arrNames = [];
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    $arrNames[] = [ 
                    'first' => ucwords(strtolower($row['first'])),
                    'last' => ucwords(strtolower($row['last']))
                  ];
}

echo json_encode($arrNames);
```

Comment: How do I get this into the array?

Comment: Not exactly, I need them to be in an array as the following: `[
    {
        "first": "Jane",
        "last": "Menson"
    },
    {
        "first": "Jake",
        "last": "Pam"
    } ]`. The first and last name should not concat also

Comment: @Ken, see my updated answer. If works for you, `accept the answer`.

Comment: Is there any way to add exceptions to what rows are applied `ucwords(strtolower` ? For example if a record says JASON keep it as JASON don't change it to Jason.

Comment: just compare the `strtoupper('JASON') = 'JASON'` if true then don't apply this otherwise use it.

Comment: So it would be `'first' => strtoupper($row['first']) == $row['first'] ? $row['first'] : ucwords(strtolower($row['first']))`

Comment: Where would I specify `JASON` in what you have above?

Comment: Are you talking about specific value `JASON` or you are checking any value with all uppercase?

Comment: I am saying if `JASON` leave as `JASON` if anything else do `ucwords(strtolower($row['first']))`

Comment: If you are only checking for JASON then do `'first' => $row['first'] == 'JASON' ? $row['first'] : ucwords(strtolower($row['first']))`

Comment: I see, and what if I was checking for `JASON` and `MARY`?

Comment: use [in_array](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) function in php.

Comment: I cannot use some and/or ?

Comment: Yes you can use `or`

Comment: Is my syntax incorrect? `'first' => $row['first'] == 'JASON' or 'MARY'` ?

Comment: No its not, if you are new to PHP, you should search in google and learn. If you ask and get result, you would not be able to learn. Best way to learn is try and look for issue and solution, if not able to then ask. Btw it would be `'first' => ($row['first'] == 'JASON' or $row['first'] == 'MARY')`

Comment: I appreciate your help, Yes I am learning PHP right now, just was confused